# Laravel-Excel my importing logic is too slow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have this code to import to database some excel file. It takes too much time, more than 30 seconds, so php sends me an error due max time limit. I don't want to disable that time, nor put more time on php (`set_timeout(0)`). For 20 registries it takes les than 30 seconds but I need to do it with 1000 registries aprox:

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
if($request->file('import_file')){
    $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    })->get()->toArray();
    if(!empty($data) && (count($data)> 0)){
        $errorCaga = false;
        $array_errores = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $r_ex_bases = AdminResolucionExenta::where('nombre',$value["r._ex._bases"])->pluck( 'id_resolucion_exenta')->first();
            $decreto_precio_nudo = AdminDecretoPrecioNudo::where('nombre',$value["dec._p._nudo"])->pluck( 'id_decreto_precio_nudo')->first();
            $modalidad = AdminModalidade::where('nombre',$value["modalidad"])->pluck( 'id_modalidad')->first();
            $licitacion = AdminLicitacione::where('nombre',$value["licitacion"])->pluck( 'id_licitacion')->first();
            $tipo_bloque = AdminTipoBloque::where('nombre',$value["tipo_bloque"])->pluck( 'id_tipo_bloque')->first();
            $bloque = AdminBloque::where('nombre',$value["bloque"])->pluck( 'id_bloque')->first();
            $distribuidora = AdminDistribuidora::where('nombre',$value["distribuidora"])->pluck( 'id_distribuidora')->first();
            $punto_oferta = AdminPuntoOferta::where('nombre',$value["punto_oferta"])->pluck( 'id_punto_oferta')->first();
            $punto_compra = AdminPuntoCompra::where('nombre',$value["punto_compra"])->pluck( 'id_punto_compra')->first();
            $generadora = AdminGeneradora::where('nombre',$value["generadora"])->pluck( 'id_generadora')->first();
            if(is_null($r_ex_bases) || is_null($decreto_precio_nudo) || is_null($modalidad) || is_null($licitacion) || is_null($tipo_bloque) || is_null($bloque) || is_null($distribuidora) || is_null($punto_oferta) || is_null($punto_compra) || is_null($generadora)){
                array_push($array_errores,$value);
                $errorCaga = true;
            }else{
                $datos = new AdminContrato;
                $datos->resolucion_exenta_id = $r_ex_bases;
                $datos->decreto_precio_nudo_id = $decreto_precio_nudo;
                $datos->modalidad_id = $modalidad;
                $datos->licitacion_id = $licitacion;
                $datos->tipo_bloque_id = $tipo_bloque;
                $datos->bloque_id = $bloque;
                $datos->distribuidora_id = $distribuidora;
                $datos->punto_oferta_id = $punto_oferta;
                $datos->punto_compra_id = $punto_compra;
                $datos->generadora_id = $generadora;
                $datos->save();
            }
        }
 //some more code to return and exit.
```

How could I do this more efficient? I'm new to Laravel, I know that creating an object `new AdminContrato` isn't the best way. Would the `chunk()` method helps on this?

Comment: What are you using to read the Excel file?

Comment: Laravel-excel as the topic says

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use Eloquent object's save method, when you should be using the query builder or raw SQL insert statements.

Comment: Does your `id_` columns have indices? What happens if your leave the inside of the `foreach()` empty? How big are the Excel files?

Comment: @bassxzero How would be using query builder?

Comment: @camilo the excel weights like 300KB, it has 1700 rows aprox. No, it doesn't have indices. If it's empty there some code to handle it but I didn't put it.

Comment: @pmirnd https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts

Comment: If by removing the code inside the `foreach()`, the script runs faster, then it could be the queries. I would try adding indices for all the `id_` columns.

Comment: I guess if you try to code in english, more people will try to answer. Good luck (no irony).

Comment: @Kyslik I think that the name of the models and vars are irrelevant, they are just proper nouns.